# MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others) Laravel Envio de formulário via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Tenho um formulário simples e estou fazendo o envio dele para o controller pelo Ajax, mas o meu problema é que após clicar no botão de submit ele não chama a requisição Ajax no meu Jquery e já encaminha direto para este erro.

[image: Erro ao dar submit no formulário]

Eu tenho um outro controller e copiei tudo o processo mudando apenas os inputs e os campos

Código javascript que o sistema deveria passar após o submite

```
 jQuery("#formRecebimento").submit(function(){
            var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();            
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'recebimentos/cadastrar',
                data: dados,
                beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', $("#token").attr('content'));},                
                success: function(data) {
                    if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
                        alert(data.id);                        
                        $('#modalAddCliente').modal('hide');

                    }else{
                        printErrorMsg(data.error);
                    }
                }


            });

            return false;
    });
```

Mas ele nem chega nessa parte do código!

PS: EM OUTRO CONTROLLER EU MONTEI DA MESMA FORMA E FUNCIONOU CORRETAMENTE

ROUTES

```
$this->group(['prefix' => 'recebimentos'], function(){
    $this->post('cadastrar', 'RecebimentoController@store');
    $this->post('atualizar', 'RecebimentoController@update');
    $this->post('detelar', 'RecebimentoController@destroy');

    $this->get('/', 'RecebimentoController@index');
});
```

CONTROLLER PS: O INDEX ESTA FUNCIONANDO NORMALMENTE E EU DEIXEI O STORE COMENTADO PARA ENCONTRAR ONDE ESTA O ERRO E ELE NEM CHEGA NO MEU CONTROLLER

```
public function store(Request $request){      /*
         $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'data_receb' => 'required|date|after:start_date',
            'valor' => 'required',
            'cliente_id' => 'required',
            'plano_contas' => 'required|max:100',                  
        ]);
        if ($validator->passes()) {

            $recebimento = Recebimento::create($request->all());
            return response()->json($recebimento);
        }
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);      */  

        return "asefa";
    }
```

PARTE DA DEFINIÇÃO DO FORMULÁRIO

```
<form id="formRecebimento" method="post">

                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="data_receb">Data do Recebimento*</label>
                                            <input type="date" class="form-control data_receb" id="data_receb" name="data_receb" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

SCRIPT GLOBAL PS: TENHO UM ARQUIVO JS PARA CADA CONTROLLER

```
$.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-XSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não esta tratando o evento de submit no jquery corretamente.

**O que esta acontecendo é:**

Quando você clica no enviar do form, ele dispara o evento submit, Jquery pega esse evento más por padrão ele continua (com o atributo action do form) e não com o ajax que você criou.

**Como Resolver:**

o certo de você fazer é bloquear esse "default" e tratar dentro do `$('#form').submit();`

Basta fazer isso:

```
jQuery("#formRecebimento").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //Resto do Código
});
```

**Por que usar o PreventDefault?**

Por que ele cancela o evento se for cancelável, sem parar a propagação do mesmo.

Nesse caso ele continua no evento Submit do `<form>` Porém quem controla isso é seu código JS

**Algumas Referências:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960586/7705942

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault